# useState not registering on first render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very simple react application.  I am trying to set a state variable and then immediately after console.log that variable but am getting a blank value.

```
var [techFilterTerm, setTechFilterTerm] = useState('');
setTechFilterTerm('Test');
console.log(techFilterTerm);
```

I expect on the first render this would show "Test" in the console - it however shows the empty string.  What is going on here?

Comment: `setTechFilterTerm('Test');` is `async` thus for first render it would be default value which is `''`

Comment: Does it return a promise - aka, is there a way to await the result?

Comment: It dont, but as per the docs it `enqueues` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate and as per that `During the initial render, the returned state (state) is the same as the value passed as the first argument (initialState).`. I also went to the codebase itself https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactHooks.js#L72 and it calls internal dispatcher which is probably used for VDOM diffing inside Fiber

Comment: Why not do `useState('Test')` if you want the initial value to be `'Test'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to know the updated value and for that you can use useEffect api which will get called whenever there is change in one of the value you want to observe. The values you want to observe you need to pass as second parameter as array in useEffect. In your case you want to know the updated value for techFilterTerm so you can pass techFilterTerm as second argument to useEffect as below.

```
 useEffect(() => {
      //here you will get the updated value whenever there is change in value
  },[techFilterTerm]);
```

here is the link for more info on useEffect.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html